# I am trying to integrate fabric Crashlytics . First I integrated plugin and I am getting error I am not able to resolve

Tags: android

> Error:No cached version listing for io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+
>   available for offline mode.

Comment: provide more details..!!

Comment: Avoid using + symbol on gradle plugin.Use exact version of the plugin. and Go to file->Invalidate caches and restart.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uncheck "Offline work" in Android Studio

File->Settings->Gradle->Global Gradle Settings

or in OSX:

Preferences->Gradle->Global Gradle Setting

or in more recent versions:

File->Settings->Build, Execution, Deployment->Build tools->Gradle

Resync the project, for example by restarting the Android Studio